# In triangle ABC. O is the circumcentre and H is the orthocentre. Of the circle BOC passes through H, prove that angle A = 60

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> In triangle $ABC$. $O$ is the circumcentre and $H$ is the orthocentre. If the circle $BOC$ passes through $H$, prove that $\measuredangle A = 60^{\circ}$.

How do I prove it using the theorems of plane geometry and properties of triangles.

Comment: It seems not true i general. Consider a rectangular triangle with $C=H$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

As I see, the circle BOC is the circumcircle of triangle BOC. We have four point B, H, O, C are in the same circle, so $\angle BHC = \angle BOC$.

Note that $\angle BHC = 180^\circ - \angle A$ and $\angle BOC = 2 \angle A$.

Summing up, we have $2\angle A = 180^\circ - \angle A$, or $\angle A = 60^\circ$.

Answer (score 0):

$\measuredangle BOC=2\alpha$ and $\measuredangle BHC=\beta+\gamma=180^{\circ}-\alpha$.

Thus,
$$2\alpha=180^{\circ}-\alpha$$ or
$$\alpha=60^{\circ}$$ and we are done!